# Is there any Rules Engine/Inference Engine for Go

Tags: go, rule-engine

We want to implement our business logic using Go, but we cannot find any good implementation of rules engine/inference engine for Go. Does anyone have any experience or suggestions?

Comment: Did you find any good soliton or framework around this topic? 
@rui

Answer (score 3):

There is a project that aims to implement an ISO Prolog compiler in Go:

- [GoLog](http://godoc.org/github.com/mndrix/golog).

I haven't tested it, but given that it implements some basic Prolog, that should be quite a capable rule-based reasoning engine, AFAIS.

Otherwise, a search for "rule" over at [godoc.org](http://godoc.org) also yields a bunch of packages:

- [godoc.org/?q=rule](http://godoc.org/?q=rule)

Comment: Looking at the list over at godoc.org, godec (https://github.com/steveyen/gdec) seems to be potentially interesting , claiming to be "declarative golang data & rules processing".

Answer (score 1):

The best example of something like this to my knowledge is the 'table-driven' approach to unit tests taken in much of the standard library. For example, the [fmttests](http://golang.org/src/pkg/fmt/fmt_test.go).

Beyond that, Go is a powerful, expressive language. What do you actually need? There are a number of examples of state machine implementations in Go, and a number of web frameworks with declarative JSON configuration.

If you mean proper logic programming, there's no popular Go library for it yet.

Comment: It is not for testing purpose, we just need a temptable framework to handle boolean evaluation from a rule description file instead of hard code the logic in the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with JBoss Drools, now there's something similar in Golang. 
Check this out https://github.com/newm4n/grool

It has DSL similar to Drools DRL, called GRL.

```
rule SlowDown "When testcar is slowing down we keep decreasing the speed." salience 10  {
    when
        TestCar.SpeedUp == false && TestCar.Speed > 0
    then
        TestCar.Speed = TestCar.Speed - TestCar.SpeedIncrement;
        DistanceRecord.TotalDistance = DistanceRecord.TotalDistance + TestCar.Speed;
}
```

Comment: How to write the rule for "Contains" operator in GRL ? 

Rest I went through your grool repo and liked what you have done.

Comment: @Kartavya You can easily create any function inside a struct and add the struct instance into the data context. Call the function from GRL.

Comment: This project is now archived. Moved to https://github.com/hyperjumptech/grule-rule-engine

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/antonmedv/expr

It can parse next expressions:

```
# Get the special price if
user.Group in ["good_customers", "collaborator"]

# Promote article to the homepage when
len(article.Comments) > 100 and article.Category not in ["misc"]

# Send an alert when
product.Stock < 15
```

Type check them and evaluate.

Also code really good:  [image: Build Status] [image: Go Report Card] [image: Code Coverage]